# Converting DD MMM YYYY to a date field with SQL

Tags: sql, database, date, sybase

I have a string value E.g 28Dec2013 which I need to convert to a date field in SQL.

I need to convert to a date field so I can carry out calculations on the field.
For example if I query: select max(date) it returns the value of '31Oct2015' - However I know this value should be '01Jan2016 '

Does anyone have any ideas how to go about this.

I'm unsure because of the format of the string how to go about this.
I am running this on Sybase.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: is your field date or varchar type?

Comment: Of course, it is varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(thedate, 0, 2) || ' ' || SUBSTRING(thedate, 3, 3) || ' ' || SUBSTRING(thedate, 6, 4), 106) FROM calendartable;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't know Sybase I'd go with a more or less dbms independent solution:

```
SUBSTRING(col FROM 6 for 4) || CASE SUBSTRING(col from 3 for 3)
                               when 'Jan' then '01'
                               when 'Feb' then '02'
                               when 'Mar' then '03'
                               when 'Apr' then '04'
                               when 'May' then '05'
                               when 'Jun' then '06'
                               when 'Jul' then '07'
                               when 'Aug' then '08'
                               when 'Sep' then '09'
                               when 'Oct' then '10'
                               when 'Nov' then '11'
                               when 'Dec' then '12' end
                            || SUBSTRING(col from 1 for 2)
```

ANSI SQL compliant!

Comment: Hi, thanks this gave me an idea. I've posted my solution below :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),thedate,106) FROM calendartable
```

Use convert.

Value 106 is dd/mon/yy

Comment: Hi, again tried this idea and again receive the 'data type conversion is not possible. CONVERT argument does not match the required data type'

Comment: did you change `datefield` to your field name that contains the date

Comment: Hi Matt, yep ran this query - " SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),THEDATE,106) FROM CALENDARTABLE  "

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the help, I found a work around myself, see answer above :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Simple **CAST** function:

```
SELECT CAST('28Dec2013' AS DATE)
```

Query for Table:

```
  SELECT CAST(Column AS DATE) FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea, but I had tried this and have just tried running your above query and receive the 'data type conversion is not possible' error

Comment: Do you know any online editor like sqlfiddler for sybase

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I'm afraid I don't, I've just been working on a development database